# D3plus hyperlink

Tags: d3.js, d3plus

I created a simple static network with D3plus. I want to have a working hyperlink in tooltip/legend which depends on the name of selected node?
So if the node name is "Berlin" I want a link to "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlin"

How to do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using [this example](http://d3plus.org/examples/advanced/ec9a55d3eb37b6f81910/) as a starting point for creating a large tooltip with clickable content, the "html" key can be passed a function which will get passed the id of the clicked data point:

```js
var sample_data = [
  {"value": 100, "name": "Berlin"},
  {"value": 70,  "name": "London"},
  {"value": 40,  "name": "Paris"}
]

function htmlContent(id) {
  return "<a href='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + id + "'>Click Here</a>";
}

var visualization = d3plus.viz()
  .container("#viz")
  .data(sample_data)
  .id("name")
  .size("value")
  .tooltip({"html": htmlContent})
  .type("tree_map")
  .draw();
```

```html
<script src="//d3plus.org/js/d3.js"></script>
<script src="//d3plus.org/js/d3plus.js"></script>

<div id="viz"></div>
```

Comment: Additionally, if you don't want to use the full-screen tooltip, you can override the mouse click behavior as in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41153348/how-can-i-pass-a-path-to-open-window-onclick-event-in-d3plus-javascript